# Sending private transactions using ethers and hardhat

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, flashbots, private-transaction

I am using [HardHat](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/overview) and ethers to send `mint` transaction:

```js
  const ABI = (await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract")).interface

  const contract_address = "0xABCDABCD"
  const [signer] = await ethers.getSigners()

  const MyContract = await new ethers.Contract(contract_address, ABI, signer)

  tx = await MyContract.mint({ gasPrice: price * 4 })
```

Now I want the mint transaction to be private. [The doc I found was this](https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/advanced/rpc-endpoint):

```js
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://dark-red-uranium.discover.quiknode.pro/XXXXXXX");
  const network = await provider.send("eth_sendPrivateTransaction", ["FILL_ME_ARG_1"]);
```

How do I send the `mint` transaction using this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The document stating that it requires a signed transaction. With `ethers.js` you should sign the transaction locally and send it. The below should work:

```js
  provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('http://localhost:8545')
  myWallet = new ethers.Wallet("0x59c699..sample private key...", provider)
  myAddress = await myWallet.getAddress()
  raw_tx = await MyContract.populateTransaction.mint()
  console.log(raw_tx)
  //make sure "from" is "myAddress"
  raw_tx.from = myAddress
  raw_tx = await myWallet.populateTransaction(raw_tx)
  console.log(raw_tx)
  signed_tx = await myWallet.signTransaction(raw_tx)
  console.log("signed tx ", signed_tx)
  /// Continute with your eth_sendPrivateTransaction as example in document with  "tx" is the signed_tx above
  /// For example: tx = await provider.sendTransaction(signed_tx); should work with normal provider
```

By looking at the populated raw tx, you can modify the gas price before it's signed, [it may not be gasPrice field anymore after EIP 1559, depends on the blockchain](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-send-transactions-with-eip-1559)
One thing to note is that the default [JsonRpcSigner](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/jsonrpc-provider/#JsonRpcSigner) may not allow `signTransaction`, my solution is to use `Wallet` of `ethers` to import either privatekey or some menomic to sign. Not sure if there is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: When we run the 4th line `raw_tx = await MyContract.populateTransaction.mint()`, won't the transaction be submitted open to the blockchain?

Comment: No, it builds your transaction locally. There is nothing to submit because it's not signed yet.  You can look at how it is implemented here : https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/ec1b9583039a14a0e0fa15d0a2a6082a2f41cf5b/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L228-L282

Comment: If you dont trust the library to build that for you, you can just craft your own raw transaction without calling `MyContract.populateTransaction.mint()`. This link https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/#the-data-field shows you how to do it, the most important thing are the `to` field pointing to your contract instance, and the `data` field must be the 4 byte encoding of the `mint()` function, and `nonce`.